# cookie does not write

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

```
                   protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
                   {
                    base.OnInit(e);
                    HttpCookie objCookieSessionInfo = new HttpCookie("cookieInfo");
                    objCookieSessionInfo.Values.Add("lastLogOnDateTime", "value");
                    objCookieSessionInfo.Values.Add("userDisplayName", "value");
                    objCookieSessionInfo.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(objCookieSessionInfo);
                   }
```

Client machine is Windows 7 ultimate.With language pack Hindi. 
Accessing website from server.i have above code in my aspx code behind file.
but cookie does not write.

but when i host website on Client machine IIS then cookie write read properly.

How can i handle this.

Comment: You are not seeing the cookie being sent when you inspected the HTTP request?

Comment: Darin i have Edit quetion

Comment: Darin but when i host website on Client machine IIS then cookie write read properly.